# How can I access my Ubuntu phone over ssh?

Tags: apt, ssh, ubuntu-touch, openssh

Whenever I try to run `apt-get install openssh-server` I get the following errors:

```
root@ubuntu-phablet:/home/hablet# apt-get install openssh-server
W: Not using locking for read only lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock
E: Unable to write to /var/cache/apt
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

Comment: Exactly the same error

Comment: Same error for me doing same thing - ubuntu 11.04.

Comment: @Malee 11.04 is end of life, you can't get help for 11.04 here because of that.  Upgrade to 12.04 or newer, or to a supported release, and then we can help you fix it.

Comment: Ubuntu touch does not have the software center yet and updating is terminal only, which i did not do as i tried to install openssh.

Comment: Ok since i did not change too much yet, do you think formatting my storage and reflashing ubuntu helps?

Comment: Tried it, still getting the same mistake...

Comment: What command do you reflash with?

Comment: I follow the exact instructions on https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install, the command is phablet-flash i will try another version now

Comment: Why are you using Ubuntu 11.04?

Answer (score 27):

With the official final release Ubuntu for Phones ships the "android-gadget-service" tool with which you can manage adb, mtp, USB tethering and ssh.

Connect your device via USB, enable Developer Mode in:

"System-Settings->About This Phone->Developer Mode"

...and run (from your PC, make sure to have the phone screen unlocked, else adb will refuse to let you in):

```
adb shell android-gadget-service enable ssh
```

Copy your [public key](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys) to the Phone:

```
adb shell mkdir /home/phablet/.ssh
adb push ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub /home/phablet/.ssh/authorized_keys
adb shell chown -R phablet.phablet /home/phablet/.ssh
adb shell chmod 700 /home/phablet/.ssh
adb shell chmod 600 /home/phablet/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Now you can look up your IP on the phone and use ssh to connect:

```
adb shell ip addr show wlan0|grep inet
ssh phablet@<IP from above command>
```

Comment: Works great, but the last command will show no IP if the network interface is not named `wlan0`. Mine was `wlan2` for some reason.

Comment: The command:
adb push ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub /home/phablet/.ssh/authorized_keys

Gives me:
cannot stat '/home/tenleftfingers/.ssh/id_rsa.pub': No such file or directory

Comment: No need for Developer Mode or making the image writable. See [SSH Ubuntu Touch](http://askubuntu.com/questions/601910/ssh-ubuntu-touch/653595#653595) for an easy, working solution. As always with password-less authentication you need to place a `/home/phablet/.ssh/authorized_keys` file (with a public key of the PC you're using to access the Ubuntu Touch device) on your device. Running `ssh -v phablet@<ip-address>` (verbose) helps to debug login or permission issues.

Comment: @orga Does it broadcast with zeroconf (avahi-daemon)? That way I can see my device on nautilus and transfer files over sftp.

Comment: I also had to add permissions: chmod o-w ~/

Comment: For me, the phablet was only answering on IPv6. So I had to use `ssh -6 phablet@ipv6-addr%ethernet-interface` to get it to work.

Answer (score 20):

To activate ssh access **entirely over wifi**, **without developer mode** on the phone, **without any special tooling** on your computer and **without using USB**:

1. If you don't already have an ssh keypair, type `ssh-keygen` on your computer and follow the instructions to generate one.
2. Install the Terminal app on the phone from the App Store.
3. Open a Terminal and type (this is easier with the phone in a landscape orientation):

   ```
   sudo setprop persist.service.ssh true
   mkdir -pm700 ~/.ssh
   ip addr
   nc -l 1234 > ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
   ```

   (the last command will hang; this is expected)
4. Look for your phone's IP address in the Terminal as returned by the `ip addr` command above.
5. On your computer, type (replacing `192.0.2.1` with your phone's IP address from above):

   ```
   nc 192.0.2.1 1234 < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
   ```

   If successful, the last command on your phone's Terminal will now succeed.
6. On your computer, type (again replacing `192.0.2.1` with your phone's IP address from above):

   ```
   ssh phablet@192.0.2.1
   ```
7. If your phone's IP address changes, you will need to use `ip addr` in the Terminal app on your phone again and adjust your ssh command accordingly.

Comment: **Very** informative answer as it does away with the adb shell and USB cable. Two thumbs up!

Comment: Indeed Veryvery usefull answer. +2

Comment: @ogra (who knows better than me) tells me that `sudo android-gadget-service enable ssh` superceded `sudo setprop persist.service.ssh true` and should be used instead, but I haven't tested this.

Comment: This should be the top answer as with the BQ Aquarius 5 the phone can't be discovered with the android method.

Answer (score 15):

**OpenSSH server** is now (as of 13-Sep-2013) pre-loaded with **Ubuntu Touch** install.
However, it is also disabled *by default*.
You also don't want SSH operating from **root**.

---

You need to type the following, using a USB connection to the device:

```
adb shell
su - phablet
sudo tee /etc/init/ssh.override < /dev/null
```

To revert to disabled

```
echo "manual" | sudo tee /etc/init/ssh.override
```

---

### **UPDATE: (09-Mar-2014)**

***The answer above is no longer current.***

- As of early March 2014, while the file **`/etc/init/ssh.override`** still exists, changing its contents does not allow SSH (actually the **sshd** daemon) to run on startup.
- The recent builds (tested for **226**, but possibly earlier) now support a new meta-flag **persist.service.ssh**, to allow SSH (**sshd** daemon) to re-start on startup.

Get to command prompt (on device)

```
adb shell
su - phablet
```

Start SSH, and set flag

```
sudo service ssh start
sudo setprop persist.service.ssh true
```

Restart device

```
sudo reboot
```

The SSH daemon should auto-start

```
sudo service ssh status
```

---

To disable SSH auto-start, change the flag:

```
sudo setprop persist.service.ssh false
```

Comment: why do you need to sudo everything after going su -?

Comment: The line **`su - phablet`** changes the **user** to *phablet*, not super-user. It is generally *best practice* to use **least privilege**, so as to be less vulnerable to attack.

Comment: this answer needs updating, look at @ogra's

Comment: Will need to review and try that method first.

Answer (score 0):

Try making it writable and reboot:

```
touch /userdata/.writable_image
```

Edit: When you build it use the `--pending` switch [Updates to phablet-flash](http://sergiusens.github.io/posts/updates-to-phablet-flash.html)

Edit: [System images now the recommended way to deploy and update Ubuntu Touch](http://ubuntu-discourse.org/t/system-images-now-the-recommended-way-to-deploy-and-update-ubuntu-touch/1008)

Comment: This answer is no longer relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Install Ubuntu SDK and click "Open SSH connection do the device" in the devices panel. Bonus: you won't resist to writing a new Scope...

Answer (score 0):

I have just found a faster (quick and dirty) way **(Attention: it is not secure!)**:

1) Install the terminal app and open it

2) switch to root

```
sudo su
```

(enter you screen lock password)

2) Enter the following commands:

```
echo "PasswordAuthentication yes" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config
echo "AllowUsers phablet" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config
/usr/sbin/sshd
```

Now your ssh server is running and it will accept your screen lock code as a password! **Attention: it is very easy to brute-force now! Please change your settings immediately** (now you can do it in a comfortable way, after you connect via ssh from you PC).

Since you run the sshd manually, the /etc/init/ssh.override file is not applied anymore...

So to connect from your PC:

```
ssh phablet@x.x.x.x
```

where x.x.x.x is an IP-address of your phone, which you can find by typing

```
ifconfig
```

in the terminal of your phone.

Enjoy!

**UPDATE**: it could be, that after update, sshd is failing to start because it cannot open host keys, then just regenerate them:

```
/usr/bin/ssh-keygen -A
```

If it fails because /var/run/sshd is missing, just create it:

```
mkdir /var/run/sshd
chmod 755 /var/run/sshd
```