# How to transfer files from a windows environment to Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: windows, ubuntu-touch, file-sharing

I installed the Ubuntu Touch on my Galaxy Nexus by flashing it thru recovery, but I can't transfer files from my computer to it. Right now I'm in a Windows environment (Windows 8) and I don't want to install Ubuntu just to transfer files. Is there something I can do to transfer them (besides using `adb push`)?
Right now my computer detects my Ubuntu Touch phone like this:
http://puu.sh/4X9Mb.png
http://puu.sh/4X9Mn.png

If I try to create folders inside this folder or try to paste anything it says I don't have permission. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: What version of **Windows**? What version of **MTP** does this support?

Comment: It is specified on the question (Windows 8). I'm assuming both Windows and Ubuntu Touch should support a compatible version, since I saw [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ArLs7UPtu-hJdDZDNWliMmV1YUJ3Zk1pQlpDdGp4VFE&usp=sharing) that Ubuntu Touch for Galaxy Nexus now supports MTP.

Comment: Regarding my close vote ("unclear"): This question seems worded wrongly: it is asking about windows software (=off topic) but the problem seems to be permissions on the device.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Drag and drop from Ubuntu desktop to Ubuntu phone](http://askubuntu.com/questions/640089/drag-and-drop-from-ubuntu-desktop-to-ubuntu-phone)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the easiest way that comes to my mind is to [enable SSH](https://askubuntu.com/questions/348714/how-can-i-access-my-ubuntu-phone-over-ssh/601972#601972) (no adb, no developer mode) on your Ubuntu Touch device and transfer your files using [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php)