# Drag and drop from Ubuntu desktop to Ubuntu phone

Tags: unity, ubuntu-touch

Any tips or advice on dragging `.jpeg` files from the PC desktop to the Ubuntu phone?

I get an error image message every time.

Comment: You forgot to say what exactly is the error message. Is it MTP error related?

Comment: I didn't enable developer mode. Thank you for replying, its much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable the developer mode in the system settings of your Ubuntu phone:

Open system settings, go to the bottom and tap <kbd>About this phone</kbd>, again to the bottom, and tap <kbd>Developer mode</kbd> and turn it on.

Now you'll be able to drag-and-drop...

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: Brilliant it worked thank you. Having been in Apple kindergarten for a good part of my life, I forgot about that, and formatting SD cards too!