# How do I clear cache or make space on Ubuntu phone?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone, cache, bq

My Ubuntu Touch phone (BQ 4.5) is running out of storage. I'm looking for a GUI way to make space, most likely by clearing a .cache folder. I'm happy to install apps, use the file manager, or use any other non-terminal options as a normal phone user would.

Comment: wasn't there an option to clear cache in recovery mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but there is no app that does exactly what you want; the file manager you mentioned comes closest.  Then you can access most files using a GUI and can delete anything you want.

If you want to do more, you need to put your phone [in developer mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/640089/drag-and-drop-from-ubuntu-desktop-to-ubuntu-phone) and run the file manager as root as well.

**Warning**: you *can* delete everything when using the root mode, including system files which can then brick your phone.  *(No, I haven't tested this!)*

Comment: Don't thank me!  **;-)** If you like my answer, just click the little grey **☑** under the "0" now turning it into beautiful green.  If you do not like my answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0, and if you *really* like my answer, click on the little grey checkmark *and* the little up-arrow...  If you have any further questions, go to http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask

Comment: That is sadly probably the correct answer. The good news is, there is no need to be in developer mode neither root do delete most of the files in .cache folder using file manager (select one by one folder as file manager does not have "select all" option.
Yet, for a normal phone user this is not acceptable and should be automatic somehow. Or button should be added somewhere insetting.

Comment: Thanks for the feed-back.  Answer edited, question upvoted!  **;-)**  Don't forget that you have the first version of Ubuntu Touch, so in a few years when it has a majority market share, you can brag: "Hah, back when I got my First Ubuntu Phone, you couldn't even delete the cache without dropping into the terminal or the file manager."  You're an early adopter just like me...  **;-)**