# Ubuntu Touch ssh connection refused

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-touch, nexus-4

running Ubuntu Touch on a Nexus 4. I've installed ssh server and have followed the instructions available in the wiki to ssh into the phone, but it tells me connection is refused. Doing the standard ssh phablet@192.168.x.x (getting IP address from ifconfig). I've made the image writable. I've enabled ssh. Now I'm at a loss.

Comment: By default SSH is disabled, and SSH-server is already installed. See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/348714/ubuntu-touch-apt-get-install-openssh-server-error **What beta-release/date of *Ubuntu-Touch* are you using?**

Comment: No need to make the image writable. See [SSH Ubuntu Touch](http://askubuntu.com/questions/601910/ssh-ubuntu-touch/653595#653595) for a working solution. As always with password-less authentication you need to place a `/home/phablet/.ssh/authorized_keys` file (with a public key of the PC you're using to access the Ubuntu Touch device) on your device.

Answer (score 0):

There is an override file /etc/init/ssh.override, which disables password login to ssh. If you were to do

```
$ ssh phablet@192.168.x.x -v
```

from your client, you will see something like

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
```

so, the only authentication option by default is publickey and not password. To enable the password authentication, you can either remove this override file, which you won't be able to do for some reason I can't figure out, or simply empty out the file

```
sudo tee /etc/init/ssh.override < /dev/null
```