# Ubuntu touch - remote access to device

Tags: ubuntu-touch, android, tablet, nexus-7

in our company we developed an android app installed on nexus 7 tablets and on tablet we release to several customers. This app stays in foreground active 24/7 but we have problems in monitoring  the devices due to the restrictive access policies of unrooted Android devices.

We can't for example reboot the device remotely.

We are evaluating the possibility of installing Ubuntu touch to replace android on this tablets.
Does Ubuntu touch offer more freedom for the remote access of the device? May I do remotely everything I could do normally with the tablet?

Moreover, are the apps developed with ubuntu sdk stable enough to run 24/7?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To allow communication between your Nexus 7 and your host system you'll need to enable the developer mode on your Ubuntu-touch device.

Go to System Settings -> About this phone -> Developer mode:

[image]

With the developer mode activated, you have several options to start a ssh connection to your device:

1. From the Ubuntu SDK (you can even reboot from there):

   [image]
2. Using the `phablet-tools` package (`sudo apt-get install phablet-tools`):

   Start the connection with `phablet-shell` and once connected type `sudo reboot` as you would normally do on a desktop system:

   ```
   $ phablet-shell
   /home/sylvain/.ssh/known_hosts updated.
   Original contents retained as /home/sylvain/.ssh/known_hosts.old
   Warning: Permanently added '[localhost]:2222' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
   Welcome to Ubuntu Utopic Unicorn (development branch) (GNU/Linux 3.4.0-3-flo armv7l)

    * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/
   Last login: Fri Oct 17 09:50:34 2014 from localhost.localdomain
   phablet@ubuntu-phablet:~$ sudo reboot
   [sudo] password for phablet:
   ```

Comment: Thanks Sylvain, do you think enabling this developer mode on devices released to customers is a good practise? 
Moreover, is there the possibility that Ubuntu in the future will remove or limit this freedom of access?
Thanks again

Comment: @frankieta Enabling the developer mode to test your app is ok, but no, delivering a product with this mode enabled by default is a bad idea / a security hole. Unfortunately I can't tell you how this feature will evolve. To follow the ubuntu-touch development you can subscribe/post to the mailing list (https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-phone). You may also find this [post](https://lists.launchpad.net/ubuntu-phone/msg09773.html) interesting.

Comment: Do you have a link to some detailed technical info like this on Ubuntu Phone??? (or should I ask a question?)  ;-)

Comment: @Fabby It depends on what sort of info you'd like to find. You may have better luck on the phone mailing list for technical details.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu Touch 15.04 r4 I was able to enable SSH following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/348714/how-can-i-access-my-ubuntu-phone-over-ssh/601972#601972) elegant method using good old netcat.

Now it is possible to reboot the device remotely with just `ssh phablet@PHONEIP sudo reboot`