# How can I connect via ssh to my ubuntu phone?

Tags: networking, ubuntu-touch

I 've tried to connect via `ssh` to my phone, but the phone offers only `authmethod_is_enabled publickey` and no user-password method. I've also changed the `sshd_config` in:

```
PasswordAuthentication yes
AllowUsers  phablet
```

But it doesn't work?

Comment: Your question is already answered here: http://askubuntu.com/a/599041/290562

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I access my Ubuntu phone over ssh?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/348714/how-can-i-access-my-ubuntu-phone-over-ssh)

Answer (score 0):

If your PC is running Ubuntu, try installing the package "phablet-tools" and then use "phablet-shell" while the device is plugged to USB. That should deploy a ssh key for you. After that, it should work fine with normal ssh and through WiFi too.

Answer (score 0):

Stop ssh if it is already running. And then run

```
 /usr/sbin/sshd
```

By this way, it will work, cause you are now running sshd manually and /etc/init/ssh.override is not applied.

**However, it is not secure, since your password should be easy to brute-force now (unless you are not using 20-charachter password for screen lock:)**

Connect to your phone as phablet@x.x.x.x and your screen lock code as password. Do not forget to reconfigure ssh safely!