# Ubuntu Aquaris E4.5 symlink

Tags: phone, symbolic-link, transfer

I have an Ubuntu Aquaris E4.5 phone and looking for and easy way of transferring multiple photo's from the SD card to my linux PC.

I have installed WifiTransfer which uses a file .local/share/wifitransfer.sil, I tried to create a symlink (never done this before). After typing the command to create the symlink I get the message "Operation not permitted".

Is the a better way to transfer batches of images?
Is it possible create symlinks?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is a sshfs option.

SSH must be activated (there is a procedure that involves `adb`).

RSA authentication should be set up to avoid entering the password every time (there is another procedure that involves `ssh-keygen` and `ssh-copy-id`).

The phone on my WiFi has an IP 192.168.0.11.

It is accessible on the desktop Ubuntu through the file manager using address `sftp://phablet@192.168.0.11/home/phablet`

Answer (score 0):

Velkan thanks for help, I ended up doing a reset of my phone. Then, using this post

[How can I access my Ubuntu phone over ssh?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/348714/how-can-i-access-my-ubuntu-phone-over-ssh)

and in particular the post that starts

To activate ssh access entirely over wifi, without developer mode on the phone, without any special tooling on your computer and without using USB:

I am now able to explore my phone over wifi.