# Unable to establish SSH connection with UbuntuPhone with phablet-shell

Tags: 16.04, ubuntu-touch, adb

I have my Meizu MX4 with OTA-13 attached with my Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop via a USB cable. The developer mode is enabled and I am able to connect to it with `adb shell` successfully.

However when I try connecting with `phablet-shell`, I get this error:

```
Host [localhost]:2222 not found in /home/ahmad/.ssh/known_hosts
ls: cannot access '/home/ahmad/.ssh/*.pub': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

So, for an ssh connection you will need a set of keys, a running ssh server on the host device, and a client to log in with.

Be sure that the files in which the keys reside, have the correct permissions for your purpose. It might also be necessary for those files to be kept in a particular directory. The adb-shell will help you do this if phablet-shell has snags.

Worth noting that the ubuntu 14.04 phablet-tools package does not have a phablet-shell binary, so you might need to look around for an updated package.

The ssh-keygen command will generate keys for you (read the manpage).
If the usb cable is not necessary, and you have wifi working on the phablet, then you could try using the terminal app to set things up... getting PUBLIC keys into .ssh/authorized_keys can be done by pasting from e'mail if all else fails (typing them in would be a drag).

2222 is a port number.

Maybe try this:  http://sturmflut.github.io/ubuntu/touch/2015/05/08/hacking-ubuntu-touch-part-5-adb-shell-vs-phablet-shell/

You might also like this answer: [How can I access my Ubuntu phone over ssh?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/348714/how-can-i-access-my-ubuntu-phone-over-ssh/601972#601972)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/623547)

Comment: I appreciate the criticism KasiyA, although there was no actual question, and the title equally implied that an ssh connection was desired.