# After upgrade to OTA-15 osk isn't launched when tapping input field for my Nexus 4

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-4

I upgraded my Nexus 4 to OTA-15 this morning, and when it restarted the on screen keyboard isn't launched when I tap an input field - meaning that I can't enter my password and am effectively locked out of my phone. Help?

Comment: Can you ssh or open a terminal into your phone?

If you haven't done it before check the answer on this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/348714/how-can-i-access-my-ubuntu-phone-over-ssh/599041#599041

IF you can get access to your phone logs it might be easier to find out whats going on.

Comment: I restored the phone to original settings, in the hope of being able to switch back to OTA-14. So I can access the phone now, and had recently backed up my important info. Unfortunately, to enable developer mode requires that I set a password, and since the on screen keyboard doesn't launch I am unable to set a password or do anything that requires text input via the osk.